# Move row to new sheet base on cell's function value - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

This script working fine when i Input "XONG" in column 7 (G)
But i want it to work automaticaly, instead of manualy input "XONG" in column 7
My function in column 7 : =IF(AND((F3=0);D3<>0);"XONG";"") - This function return "XONG", but the script is not trigger
Thank for your helps guys.

```
    function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with yes/no is col 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "DATA" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "XONG") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("XONG");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: onEdit triggers are only activated by user changes. It can not be triggered by a script or formula.

Comment: Yep, instead try triggering your function every minute or something like that

Comment: yes. can you guys please give me a sample. I'm newbie

Comment: I changed "function onEdit(event)"  to "function onOpen()" but nothing happen

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Clarify if you want to run this function once, or periodically.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, i will try to ask better question. I want to run this function anytime a value on the sheet edited

Comment: @HiểnHồ Here is the documentation for simple triggers: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started. Try implementing `onEdit`

Comment: thank @Aerials, i tried onOpen(). Also not working

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers). They are very easy to set up using the UI. See [managing triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) or programmatically further down in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This is on edit function which means it just work when you make edit manually only